# gap_bridge_mode prompt when starting a PhoneGap application

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am building a Sencha Touch application that I then build using PhoneGap. When I installel the application on my android device for testing I got a strange prompt box asking me to provide a gap_bridge_mode?! What is this and how do I get rid of it (the prompt).

In my current situation I just click the Ok button without providing any value and all works fine. However I cannot release the application with this thing "welcoming" the user.

Please, help!

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: I think I found what the problem was. In my phonegap config file I indicated the use of phonegap 2.0.0 - the latest available version on the build server - while in the index.html I was loading the 2.1.0 - the latest version available for download. After I changed index.html to point to version 2.0.0 I don't get this message anymore. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found what the problem was. In my phonegap config file I indicated the use of phonegap 2.0.0 - the latest available version on the build server - while in the index.html I was loading the 2.1.0 - the latest version available for download.

After I changed index.html to point to version 2.0.0 I don't get this message anymore.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, the library and js must match version wise.